# Extract cell value from html table using bash

Tags: html, regex, bash, html-parsing

I am trying to create a BASH/Perl script which would get a specific value from a dynamic html table.

Here is a sample of my page

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="background-color:#FFFFCC" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">

<tr align="center">

<th>Environment</th><th>Release Track</th><th>Artifact</th><th>Name</th><th>Build #</th><th>Cert Idn</th><th>Build Idn</th><th>Request Status</th><th>Update Time</th><th>Log Info.</th><th>Initiator</th>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>DEV03</td><td>2.1.0</td><td>abpa</td><td>ecom-abpa-ear</td><td>204</td><td>82113</td><td>171242</td><td>Deployed</td><td>3/18/2013 3:10:58 PM</td><td width="70">Log info</a></td><td>CESAR</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>DEV03</td><td>2.1.0</td><td>abpa</td><td>abpa_dynamic_config_properties</td><td>20</td><td>82113</td><td>167598</td><td>Deployed</td><td>3/18/2013 2:32:27 PM</td><td width="70">Log info</a></td><td>CESAR</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

My goal is to get this value from this cell.

"Deployed"

Another way to look at it...

Retrieve all data under the "Request Status" column

The value "Deployed" is dynamic and could change.

I have tried the following:

```
sed -e 's/>/>\n/g' abpa_cesar_status.txt | egrep -i "^\s*[A-Z]+&lt;/td&gt;
" | sed -e 's|&lt;/td&gt;||g' | grep Deployed
```

But that only greps for "Deployed"

Any ideas?

Comment: You mentioned Perl. So use [HTML::TableExtract](http://p3rl.org/HTML::TableExtract).

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/perl for examples of how to properly parse HTML with Perl modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: *Really* **don't use regular expressions:** http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/140740

Comment: your document output is ill-formed, is it normal/excpected or a typo ? Here is a well-formed version : http://pastebin.com/R8RGX1T9

Comment: i can't look at the well-formed versions since my work blocks those links

Comment: just tested this
awk -F "</*td>|</*tr>" '/<\/*t[td]>.*[A-Z]/ {print $8, $16 }' abpa_cesar_status.txt | grep ecom-abpa-ear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your **document output is ill-formed** (lack some opening `<a>`), is it normal/excpected or a typo ? Otherwise, here is a [well-formed version](http://pastebin.com/R8RGX1T9).

#### Command

I like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php), simple and straight forward XPath for short tests:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//table/tr/td[position()=8]" -v "./text()" -n
```

#### Explaination

```
sel   (or select)        - Select data (mode) or query XML document(s) (XPATH, etc)
-t or --template         - start a template
-m or --match <xpath>    - match XPATH expression
-v or --value-of <xpath> - print value of XPATH expression
-n or --nl               - print new line
```

#### Output

```
Deployed
Deployed
# plus empty-cell
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a parser such as [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) to do this.

With `xmllint` you can extract elements based on an xpath.

For example:

```
$ xmllint --html --format --shell file.html <<< "cat //table/tr/td[position()=8]/text()"
/ >  -------
Deployed
 -------
Deployed
/ >
```

The xpath `//table/tr/td[position()=8]/text()`, in the command above, returns the values from the 8th table column.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) to get everything in the 8-th column:

```
xidel your_table.html -e '//table//tr/td[8]'
```

Or if the column position can also change, get the column-number first:

```
xidel your_table.html -e 'column:=count(//table//th[.="Request Status"]/preceding-sibling::*)+1' -e '//table//tr/td[$column]'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open :F html abpa_cesar_status.txt ;
$status = count(//table/tr[1]/th[.="Request Status"]/preceding-sibling::th) ;
ls //td[count(preceding-sibling::td)=$status] ;
```

In order to use it, you have to make your html a bit more well formed, though (I had to remove `</a>` to make the script work).

Comment: Look like a nice concept/tools

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
cat your_html_file | perl -pe "s/^<\/?table.*$//g;s/^<tr .*$//g;s/<tr> (<td>.*?){8}//g;s/<th.*$//g;s/<\/.*$//g" | sed '/^$/d'
```

However, this is not how you should do it. Use existing (Perl?) software to parse html and extract your value.

**edit:** Since you changed your code (added whitespaces), this doesn't work anymore. QED.